# Javascript Escape Character

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically adding rows to a table. For one of the cells(cell8), I want to be able to click to call a javascript function (saveDeleteAction(rowIndex)) with the rowIndex as the parameter value. The HTML generated does not produce the actual value of rowIndex:

```
function addRowToTable(entity,rowIndex)
  {
    var table=document.getElementById("entity");
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell8=row.insertCell(7);
    cell8.innerHTML= saveDeleteAction(rowIndex);  
  }

function saveDeleteAction(rowIndex) {
  return '<a href=\'javascript:testing(rowIndex)\'; class="btn btn-small btn-warning"><i class="btn-icon-only icon-ok"></i></a>      <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-small"><i class="btn-icon-only icon-remove"></i></a>';
}

function testing(rowIndex){
  alert(rowIndex);
}
```

HTML GENERATED

```
<a href="javascript:testing(rowIndex)" ;="" class="btn btn-small btn-warning"><i class="btn-icon-only icon-ok"></i></a>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function saveDeleteAction(rowIndex) {
    return '<a href="javascript:testing(' + rowIndex + ');" class="btn btn-small btn-warning"><i class="btn-icon-only icon-ok"></i></a>      <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-small"><i class="btn-icon-only icon-remove"></i></a>';
}
```